# Replace a string after a pattern preserving the end of the line in a file

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to write a script that searches in a file for a pattern, and replaces the word after it, preserving the end of the line.

For example

```
something0 var1=some_val var2=some_other_val something_bla0
something1 var1=some_va2 something_bla1
something2 var1=some_va3 var2=some_other_val2
```

To be changed to:

```
something0 var1=my_val var2=some_other_val something_bla0
something1 var1=my_val something_bla1
something2 var1=my_val var2=some_other_val2
```

I dont know in advance the value of var1, but want to end up with var1=my_val, and have the end of the line unchanged.

Thank you!

Comment: try `sed 's/var1=[^ ]+/var1=my_var/'`

Comment: @PS in gnu sed you need quote `\+` for spectial meaning. Or use flag `-r`

Comment: Don't use the word pattern, it's ambiguous. Do you mean regexp or string?

Comment: I mean, for gnu sed, must be or `sed 's/var1=[^ ]\+/var1=my_var/'` or `sed -r 's/var1=[^ ]+/var1=my_var/'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as $FIELD and $VALUE don't need escaping then

```
FIELD=var1
VALUE=my_val
sed "s/$FIELD=[^ ]*/$FIELD=$VALUE/" myfile.txt
```

Comment: Hi Chrs, thank you for your reply. Unfortunatelly for some reason it adds additional symbols after the end of the value of the variable: elevator=deadline^Onsoleblank=0

Comment: It works for me on the example you provided. What are the FIELD and VALUE?

Comment: FIELD=elevator
VALUE=deadline

Comment: What does this give you?

   FIELD=elevator

    VALUE=deadline

    echo "X elevator=X X" | sed "s/$FIELD=[^ ]* /$FIELD=$VALUE /"

Comment: The output is this: X elevator= X

Comment: I wonder is it possible because the new value is longer than the previous one, the difference in the length to result in overwriting the string that follows?

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be 3 separate lines which got squashed together

Comment: you may want to add a word boundary to eliminate matches against substrings, e.g. `not_this_var1=keep_this_value`

Comment: The result is: X elevator=deadline X

Comment: Chrs, it works fine with sed "s/$FIELD=[^ ]*/$FIELD=$VALUE/" myfile.txt. So basically what you sent, but without the blank spaces (with them it had issues if the FIELD is at the last possition on the line without a space after it's value. I still dont understand where these characters came from before, but its working now, so thank you very much for your help.

Comment: as one liner `;` after 'deadline` will help: `FIELD=elevator VALUE=deadline; echo "X elevator=X X" | sed "s/$FIELD=[^ ]* /$FIELD=$VALUE /"`

Answer (score 0):

The alternative approach using `awk` command with `gensub()` function:

```
awk -v val="my_val" '{$2=gensub(/(var1=).*/, "\\1"val, 1, $2)}1' testfile
```

The output:

```
something0 var1=my_val var2=some_other_val something_bla0
something1 var1=my_val something_bla1
something2 var1=my_val var2=some_other_val2
```

---

`$2` - points to the second field(i.e. `var1=...`)

> ***gensub(regexp, replacement, how [, target])***
>
> Search the target string *target* for matches of the regular expression *regexp*.

---

If it should replace `var1` value through all the line the simplified approach may look like below:

```
awk -v val="my_val" 'sub(/ var1=[^ ]*/, " var1="val)' testfile
```

Comment: Just playing around: `awk 'sub(/var1=[^ ]*/,"var1=my_val")' testfile`

Comment: @komar, I'm working with the second field to get a more accurate/exact replacement(in case if `var1=` could occur somewhere within other field text, like `something-var1=nothing_bla2`)

Comment: you are right, but in question was nothing about places where var1 can be. Problem what you point can be solve in gawk with word boundary `\y`, or directly by putting space before `var1=`

Comment: @komar, I've added it as simplified approach

Answer (score 0):

another attempt changing second field by sub

```
awk '{sub(/=some_va./,"=my_val",$2)}1' file

something0 var1=my_val var2=some_other_val something_bla0
something1 var1=my_val something_bla1
something2 var1=my_val var2=some_other_val2
```